# Perl run interactive external application with callback

Tags: shell, perl, wrapper

I am looking for a way to do the following:

1. Have a perl script execute an external, interactive shell program
2. Capture STDIN and STDOUT for the external program
3. Bind some kind of callback sub to be executed any time the external program prints anything to STDOUT
4. Use this subroutine to parse STDOUT and if it matches a regex, print a response to STDIN for the external program.

I have found
[`Expect`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect),
and `IPC`, but everything I've found so far seems to be in the context of run -> write -> read -> exit, where I need this external application to continue running and the Perl script to continue responding until I kill both.

EDIT: I found a solution in the 'expect' module for perl, by setting the timeout to undef, and calling "exp_continue" after my logic, I was able to keep the script running and handling I/O until I kill it.

Comment: Where in Expect did you find exit?

Comment: @choroba Sorry, poor choice of words. All the examples I've found, seem to run the external program, print some stuff to STDIN, then just wait for it to exit and capture STDOUT and do stuff after it exits, as opposed to binding a subroutine to print things to STDIN based on 'new' output from STDOUT. I felt like expect should be able to do this, but I wasn't sure so I wanted to ask so I don't go down the wrong path reinventing the wheel. :)

Comment: And I just figured out a way to do it with Expect. Sorry! $ob->expect [  qr/regex1/ => sub {} ]

Comment: @ErikaF. you should post an answer to your question to help others who come here. Otherwise this question has little value.

Comment: What do you mean you *"found IPC"*? There are dozens of `IPC::*` modules; which one did you "find"?

Comment: @Erika: Please write up your solution as an answer. The primary use of Stack Overflow questions is not in helping out their author, but rather to aid the rest of the world if a similar issue occurs elsewhere. You shouod think of asking a question in the same way as creating a new page on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

> I need this external application to continue running and the perl script to continue responding until I kill both.

That's an interesting question - one possible way to solve this is with an event loop framework like [`POE`](https://metacpan.org/release/POE). Although it has a bit of a learning curve (but see the [cookbook](http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook)), I've found it great for things like specialized network servers, or for things like your case - staying interactive at the console while other things (network connections, serial ports, etc.) are handled as well.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub POE::Kernel::ASSERT_DEFAULT () { return 1 }
use POE qw/ Wheel::ReadWrite Wheel::Run /;

my @CHILD = ('perl', '-wMstrict', '-nle',
    q{ $|=1; print uc; sleep 5; print lc });

POE::Session->create( inline_states => {
    _start => sub {
        $poe_kernel->alias_set('console_handler');
        $_[HEAP]{console} = POE::Wheel::ReadWrite->new(
                InputHandle => \*STDIN, OutputHandle => \*STDOUT,
                InputEvent => 'console_input', ErrorEvent => 'console_error' );
    },
    console_input => sub {
        my ($heap, $input) = @_[HEAP,ARG0];
        if ($input=~/^(?:quit|exit)$/i) {
            $poe_kernel->post(signal_handler => 'signal_shutdown',
                'user request');
        }
        elsif ($input=~/^send\s+(.*)$/i) {
            $poe_kernel->post(child_handler => 'child_stdin', $1);
        }
        else {
            $heap->{console}->put('Unknown command - try "send ..."');
        }
    },
    console_output => sub {
        my ($heap, $output) = @_[HEAP,ARG0];
        if (defined $heap->{console})
            { $heap->{console}->put($output) }
        else # assume we're shut down, don't need to go through the wheel
            { print $output, "\n" }
    },
    console_error => sub {
        my ($op, $errnum, $errstr) = @_[ARG0..ARG2];
        $poe_kernel->post(signal_handler => 'signal_shutdown',
            $op eq 'read' && $errnum==0 ? 'EOF'
                : "console error (op $op error $errnum: $errstr)" );
    },
    console_shutdown => sub { delete $_[HEAP]{console} },
    _stop => sub {  },
}, );

POE::Session->create( inline_states => {
    _start => sub {
        $poe_kernel->alias_set('child_handler');
        $poe_kernel->post(console_handler => 'console_output',
            "Starting child...");
        $_[HEAP]{child} = POE::Wheel::Run->new( Program => \@CHILD,
            StdoutEvent  => "child_stdout", StderrEvent  => "child_stderr", );
        $poe_kernel->sig_child($_[HEAP]{child}->PID, "child_signal");
    },
    child_stdin => sub {
        my ($stdin) = $_[ARG0];
        warn localtime." Send STDIN <$stdin>\n";
        $_[HEAP]{child}->put($stdin);
    },
    child_stdout => sub {
        my ($stdout) = $_[ARG0];
        warn localtime." Got STDOUT <$stdout>\n";
        $poe_kernel->post(console_handler => 'console_output',
            "Child said <$stdout>");
    },
    child_stderr => sub {
        my ($stderr) = $_[ARG0];
        warn localtime." Got STDERR <$stderr>\n";
        $poe_kernel->post(console_handler => 'console_output',
            "Child STDERR <$stderr>");
    },
    child_signal => sub {
        my ($status) = $_[ARG2];
        $poe_kernel->post(console_handler => 'console_output',
            "Child process exited with status $status.");
        $poe_kernel->delay('child_kill');
        delete $_[HEAP]{child};
    },
    child_shutdown => sub {
        $poe_kernel->post(console_handler => 'console_output',
            "Sending child process SIGINT...");
        $_[HEAP]{child}->kill('INT');
        $poe_kernel->delay('child_kill', 5);
    },
    child_kill => sub {
        return unless defined $_[HEAP]{child};
        $poe_kernel->post(console_handler => 'console_output',
            "Sending child process SIGKILL.");
        $_[HEAP]{child}->kill('KILL');
        delete $_[HEAP]{child};
    },
    _stop => sub {  },
}, );

POE::Session->create( inline_states => {
    _start => sub {
        $poe_kernel->alias_set('signal_handler');
        $poe_kernel->sig(INT  => 'signal_shutdown');
        $poe_kernel->sig(TERM => 'signal_shutdown');
        $poe_kernel->sig(HUP  => 'signal_shutdown');
    },
    signal_shutdown => sub {
        my ($signal) = $_[ARG0];
        warn $signal ? "Got $signal, " : '', "Shutting down\n";
        $poe_kernel->post(child_handler   => 'child_shutdown');
        $poe_kernel->post(console_handler => 'console_shutdown');
        $poe_kernel->sig_handled;
    },
    _stop => sub {  },
}, );

$poe_kernel->run;
```

Example Session:

```
Starting child...
send Foo
Sat Jun  2 16:44:37 2018 Send STDIN <Foo>
Sat Jun  2 16:44:37 2018 Got STDOUT <FOO>
Child said <FOO>
send Bar
Sat Jun  2 16:44:39 2018 Send STDIN <Bar>
Sat Jun  2 16:44:42 2018 Got STDOUT <foo>
Sat Jun  2 16:44:42 2018 Got STDOUT <BAR>
Child said <foo>
Child said <BAR>
Sat Jun  2 16:44:47 2018 Got STDOUT <bar>
Child said <bar>
quit
Got user request, Shutting down
Sending child process SIGINT...
Child process exited with status 2.
```

As you can see, the console remains interactive while the child process is running, with output from the child process shown asynchronously (`send Foo`, `send Bar`, and `quit` are my console input). Note you can also use [`POE::Wheel::ReadLine`](https://metacpan.org/pod/POE::Wheel::ReadLine) instead of `POE::Wheel::ReadWrite` if you want advanced features like an input history.